# Indexed multidimensional array from PHP to javascript over JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, associative-array

Hi I have multidimensional array with db records where key is ID from database (first ID is id of workgroup, second ID is user id).

```
$users = array(
  2 => array(
    5 => array(
      'firstname' => 'John'
      'lastname' => 'Newman'
    ),
    7 => array(
      'firstname' => 'Peter'
      'lastname' => 'Dow'
    );
  ),
  12 => array(
    15 => array(
      'firstname' => 'George'
      'lastname' => 'Bush'
    ),
    30 => array(
      'firstname' => 'Ronald'
      'lastname' => 'Reagan'
    );
  );
);

echo json_encode($users);
```

In javascript I would like access to array like users.workgroupId.userId.firstname. I know that javascript hasn´t associative arrays, but I need use that kind of data from PHP. Is it possible in javascript?

Comment: Sure, JavaScript has simple objects that can be mapped from PHP. Like `jsObject = { 2: { 5: { firstname : "John", lastname: "Newman" }} }`. Usually a JSON converter like `json_encode` should just do that for you!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your code generates a valid JSON, here is a way to get the required details:

```
let workgroupId = 2; // Define your workgroup ID here
let userId = 5; // Define the user ID here

console.log(users[workgroupId][userId]. firstname); // prints `John` on the console
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear:
Associative arrays become javascript objects when converted from php with json_encode and then unserialized in js. Your array in js will look like this:

```
var users = {
   2: {
      5: {
         firstname: "John",
         lastname: "Newman"
      },
      7: {
         firstname: "Peter",
         lastname: "Dow"
      }
   },
   12: {
      15: {
         firstname: "George",
         lastname: "Bush"
      },
      30: {
         firstname: "Ronald",
         lastname: "Reagan"
      }
   }
};
```

So just acces it like you would acces every other javascript object.

Example:

```
alert(users[2][5].lastname);
```

will output 'Newman'.

Answer (score 0):

there is some syntax error in your php array. Right array is following.

```
$users = array(
  2 => array(
    5 => array(
      'firstname' => 'John',
      'lastname' => 'Newman'
    ),
    7 => array(
      'firstname' => 'Peter',
      'lastname' => 'Dow'
    )
  ),
  12 => array(
    15 => array(
      'firstname' => 'George',
      'lastname' => 'Bush'
    ),
    30 => array(
      'firstname' => 'Ronald',
      'lastname' => 'Reagan'
    )
  )
);

echo json_encode($users);
```

Now following is the javascript code.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var users={"2":{"5":{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Newman"},"7":{"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Dow"}},"12":{"15":{"firstname":"George","lastname":"Bush"},"30":{"firstname":"Ronald","lastname":"Reagan"}}};
  alert(users[2][5].firstname);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```